# Is there an easy way to convert an image to grayscale with .NET

Tags: .net, graphics, image-processing

I need to convert all the images in a folder to greyscale (I believe their gif files if that matters).  Any suggestions?  I have .NET 3.5 (sp1)

Comment: check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.formatconvertedbitmap.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can do like [this guy](https://web.archive.org/web/20141230145627/http://bobpowell.net/grayscale.aspx).
Or maybe [like so](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale)

Comment: Use the second one...you do need to use weighted values for the colors rather than an even average... the human eye does not take in all colors equally.

Comment: @nobugz they are not the same. The second example shows two different ways to do it.

Comment: They both use the ordinary 0.3/0.59/0.11-rule to transform RGB into luminance/intensity.

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches:

1. Average the red, green and blue values. Simple, but the result probably won't look right unless you weight the values first.
2. Convert the image to Hue, Lightness and Saturation values and take the lightness.

You can read images using the [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image_methods.aspx) class. There's a method to read the image from file.